# Linking error: LNK2019 & LNK1120

Tags: c++, c

First I had some OpenCL code and when I put it away in another function, I got this error, then I thought maybe its something with OpenCL, but now even my every normal code suddenly appears to report this error whenever I make new function and put main function code in those functions. I have rechecked that prototypes, functions calls and function definitions are exactly same and matches, also since I have this problem with those functions in which there are more arguments like upto 8 or 10 but I read that C/C++ functions supports more 50 or so arguments passing. The error information is:

> ImgConv.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol `"void __cdecl function(.............)  (?conv_ser@@YAXPBMPAM10HHH@Z)` referenced in function `_main`
>
> fatal error LNK1120: unresolved externals

I am reporting error that has lot of forum entries and solution information such as linking some library function or functions prototyping mistakes etc, I have read them but there is non related to my problem.

Comment: Does it work if you create a new project? Also, please provides us more information with your code, and not just the linker error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the linker input settings in your project configuration and make sure that the appropriate libraries are included (or add them to the project itself). Visual Studio doesn't do this automatically just because you add the source code to your project.

If 'conv_ser' is a function that you created make sure that the implementation for that function is available in the project. Double check to make sure that the arguments in the prototype (typically in the header) match that of the any implementation you have added.

Comment: I know this information, and conv_ser is my own function which is even in the same file. Also its prototype matches exactly with its function call and function definition................. :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting all instances of `void __cdecl function`? Just search through your project and comment it out. See if your code will compile after this.